# Join smaller data frame to larger data frame by index in tidyverse?

Tags: r, tidyverse

Suppose I have the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4))
index <- data.frame(a=c(1,3), data=c('x', 'y'))
```

I want to join df and index such that I end up with a result that has the rows of df, but with index$data joined for appropriate index$a.  For some reason, English words fail me, but 'x' should be applied to 1 and 2 (because index$a has 1, and 3 is the "next" index value), and 'y' should be applied to 3 and 4.

Here is the data I'd like to end up with:

```
df2 <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4), data=c('x', 'x', 'y', 'y'))
```

Ideally this solution is compatible with tidyverse without loading any other libraries.

Suggestions?

Comment: Just an fyi, tidyverse is just a collection of libraries, so when you load tidyverse you're actually loading at least a dozen libraries. If you're trying to keep your overhead minimal, `dplyr` is the only tidyverse library needed to do a join. Regardless of that, you're looking for a left join, and there are a lot of SO posts covering that already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want? First, join `df` and `index` and keep all observations in `df`. Then, we fill in all `NA` values with the last non-`NA` observations.

```
df %>% left_join(index, by = "a") %>% fill(data)
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! You answered so fast I can't accept for another 4 minutes, but I will.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
setDT(df)[index,  data := i.data, on = .(a)][, data := na.locf0(data)]
```